# Explain the result of Microsoft video API json for Face detection and tracking

Tags: json, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

How to plot the detected faces on to the video frames from the result json  of  face detection and tracking.   I mean, how to calculate the frame number for particular event in the Json file.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-face-and-emotion-detection) give some details in case you hadn't seen it.

In essence, the video is divided into one or more **fragments**, and each fragment is divided in to **intervals**.  There will one **event** per interval.  The times and durations of fragments and intervals are expressed in **ticks**, which you can convert to time by dividing by the **timescale**.  You can map frames to/from times using the **framerate**.

Comment: Yes @cthrash, getting the floating number while calculating the frame number using the given formula. how to map to exact frame?, tried using ceil and floor, still it not accurate!